# Suppose lim $p_n = p$ and lim $q_n = q$. If $p_n < q_n$ $\forall n \ge 1$, prove that $p \leq q$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So i'm not sure how to approach this problem.  By convergence, I know that $|p_n - p| < \epsilon$ and $|q_n - q| < \epsilon$, $\forall \epsilon$.  But where do I go from here?  I think I get the intuition - one sequence is smaller than the other, so its point of convergence is probably smaller than the other.  But how do I use the definitions of convergence to show this?  Do I have to somehow use the triangle inequality?

Comment: Try a proof by contradiction; suppose $p>q$, and choose $\displaystyle\varepsilon={p-q\over 3}$. Then, for big $n$, $p_n > q_n$.

Comment: My apologies, but I don't follow the leap in logic.  We fix $\epsilon = \frac{p - q} {3}$. How exactly does this show the contradiction for large n?

Comment: Answered below. It's probably also possible to turn the proof by contradiction into a direct proof, but contradiction was the first thing I thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose (for a contradiction) that $p>q$. Let $\displaystyle\varepsilon = {p-q\over 3}>0$. Then there are numbers $N_1,N_2$ such that $\left|{p-p_n}\right|<\varepsilon$ when $n\ge N_1$, and $\left|{q-q_n}\right|<\varepsilon$ when $n\ge N_2$. Now pick $n=\max(N_1,N_2)$. Then $p-p_n<\varepsilon$ and $q-q_n > -\varepsilon$. Subtracting the second equation from the first yields
$$(p-q)+(q_n-p_n)<2\varepsilon$$
or $$3\varepsilon+(q_n-p_n)<2\varepsilon,$$ which can be rewritten as $p_n-q_n > \varepsilon>0$. This makes $p_n>q_n$, contrary to one of your assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up.  I see that the assumption provides the needed contradiction, but I can't pick your brain as to why (well, more importantly, how) you know to use $q - q_n > - \epsilon$.  Isn't the same true for $p - p_n$?  It just seems like a random thing to bring up but makes the proof work.

Comment: It's true, but doesn't help. I wanted to show that, if $p>q$, then eventually $p_n$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $p$, and $q_n$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $q$, and thus, $p_n - q_n > \varepsilon$ for that value of $n$. To do that, you need a lower bound on $p_n$ and an upper bound on $q_n$.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that if $s_n\geq 0$, and $s_n\to s$ then $s\geq 0$ (why?).

Suppose $s<0$.

We know that for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies
$$
|s_n-s|<\epsilon
$$

Take $\epsilon = -s$, then

$$s<s_n-s<-s$$

Which implies that $s_n <0$ for some big $n$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_1 > 0$ such that $|p_n -p | < \epsilon$,for all $n >N_1$. For the same $\epsilon$, there exists $N_2 > 0$, such that $|q_n- q| <\epsilon$ for all $n > N_2$. Take $N = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$, so for all $n > N$, we have
$$ p -\epsilon < p_n < p + \epsilon$$
$$ q - \epsilon < q_n < q + \epsilon$$
Therefore,
$$ p-\epsilon < p_n < q_n < q + \epsilon $$
That is,
$$ p -\epsilon < q + \epsilon$$
Let $\epsilon \to 0$, we get $p \le q$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $p_n\to p$ iff for every nbhd $U$ of $p$, the set $\{n :p_n\not \in U\}$ is finite.

By contradiction: If $p_n\leq q_n$ for all but finitely many $n$ (a weaker condition than for all $n$) and if $q<p,$ then let $$U=(p-(p-q)/2,p+1),$$  $$V=(q-1,q+(p-q)/2).$$ The sets $\{n:p_n\not \in U\}$ and $\{n: q_n\not \in V\}$ are finite so $\{n:(p_n\not \in U)\lor (q_n\not \in V)\}$ is finite.

Hence, for all but finitely many $n$, we have $\quad p_n\in U$ and $q_n\in V.\quad$  So $ q_n<p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$ (because every member of $V$ is less than every member of $U$.) But this contradicts the hypothesis that $\{n :q_n<p_n\}$ is finite. Hence $p\leq q.$